# Tensorflow, increase CPU power?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Upon running tensorflow via python2 for a couple days now, I've noticed it is only using maximum 26% of my CPU. I have tried using the ConfigProto to increase threads (thought this might increase CPU usage, perhaps not) but no luck here. 
I feel as though, if I could up the CPU usage on Tensorflow it SHOULD compute a bit faster at least. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share more information about what you are trying to do with TensorFlow? The CPU usage is not always a good proxy for efficiency, especially if the computation doesn't have a lot of parallel work.

Comment: I'm working on a seq2seq chatbot using a embedded rnn model. It works fine, I wouldn't mind it training even faster. Just hoping to squeeze out more power from my cpu.

Comment: I'm running my rnn model based on tensorflow's rnn tutorial on Mac without GPU. In that case I got 80-90% CPU load. So I believe there should be a potential to process faster.

Comment: @Jin That's very interesting. Is there anything specific you did to achieve a load that high?

Comment: I didn't do anything special. Install Python2.7, set the python path, then use pycharm to edit/run. That it.